# calling javascript function in php, after element has been clicked x times

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, function

**php/html**

```
$i=0

for each ($x as $y => $z){

<a>click me</a>

if (++$i == 5) {break;}
}
```

**javascript**

```
function load_remaining_notifcations(){
    $.post('load_remaining_notifications.php',{},function(data){
        $('#load_remaining_notifcations').html(data);
    });
}
```

when `<a>click me</a>` has been clicked five times, I want to run a javascript function. how can i time the javascript function so it will only be called after click me has been clicked 5 times?

Comment: Two ways.... 1) define global variable in js file and increment it on each click .you can also store in cookie. 2) on each click make ajax request and increment counter and store it in session on server side. on each click check variable count and based on that perform some action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var clicks = 0;
 $('a').click(function(){
     clicks++;         
     if (clicks == 5) {
         load_remaining_notifcations();
         clicks = 0; //reset counter for another 5 click or
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// js script
var counter = 0;
function doclick() {
    counter++;
    if (counter>=5) {
        // do something
        alert("OK");
    }
}

// HTML
<a id="myanchor" href="javascript:" onclick="doclick();">click me</a>
```

**EDIT:** I see that you are using jQuery.

```
// js
$("a#myanchor").click(function() {
    if (this.counter == undefined) this.counter = 0;
    this.counter++;
    if (this.counter >= 5) {
        load_remaining_notifcations();
    }
});
```